# How do I write the matrix for a CZ gate operating on nonadjacent qubits?

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

I'm working on a teleport protocol and I need to open the matrix of each operator, however, there's a CZ gate between q0 and q2 at the end of it and I don't know how to write the matrix for it and operate in the state.
[image]

This is the protocol, really basic, and the CZ is the last one.

Answer (score 7):

Consider that a control qubit is $q_k$ and a target qubit is $q_{k+n}$ and you want to apply operator $U$ on the target qubit. Denote $N=2^{n+1}$. Then matrix representation of this controlled $U$ is
\begin{equation}
CU=
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{\frac{N}{2}} & O_{\frac{N}{2}} \\
O_{\frac{N}{2}} & I_{\frac{N}{4}} \otimes U \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

In your case $U=Z=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, $k=0$ and $n=2$, so the matrix representation of operator $Z$ acting on $q_{2}$ controlled by $q_{0}$ is

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

You can write the controlled-phase gate, as applied to just those two qubits, as
$$
I\otimes I-2|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes |1\rangle\langle 1|.
$$
If you want these to act on qubits 1 and 3, then you need to apply identity, $I$, on the second qubit:
$$
I\otimes I\otimes I-2|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes I\otimes |1\rangle\langle 1|.
$$

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

1. SWAP q[1] and q[2]
2. Do CZ on q[0] and q[1] (note that we have q[2] in it right now)
3. SWAP q[1] and q[2]

In terms of matrices, all you need is to multiply 3 8x8 matrices.

Hope it will help.