# 2 qubit gate operation on multi qubit systems

Tags: quantum-state, matrix-representation, linear-algebra

Considering a 3 qubit system, what does the matrix operation will look like if I apply CNOT on qubit 1 and qubit 2 and then apply CNOT on qubit 1 and qubit 3?

Comment: See also this answer for general approach how to descibe a quantum gate acting on two non-adjacent qubits: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/how-do-i-write-the-matrix-for-a-cz-gate-operating-on-nonadjacent-qubits/9185#9185

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking into account this representation of the CNOT gate:

$$CNOT = | 0 \rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I + | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | \otimes X$$

We can write:

$$CNOT(1, 3) = | 0 \rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I \otimes I + | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | \otimes I \otimes X$$

$$CNOT(1, 2) = | 0 \rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I \otimes I + | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | \otimes X \otimes I$$

That's why:

\begin{align*}
&CNOT(1, 3) CNOT(1, 2) = | 0 \rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I \otimes I + | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | \otimes X \otimes X = \\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
+ 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = 
\end{align*}

$$= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answers to the related questions: [[1](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4255/9459)] and [[2](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9185/9459)].

Comment: See also this answer for general approach how to descibe a quantum gate acting on two non-adjacent qubits: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/how-do-i-write-the-matrix-for-a-cz-gate-operating-on-nonadjacent-qubits/9185#9185

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks so much